# How to find the potential, most granular, datatype of objects currently stored as Strings in java?

Tags: java, database, types, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am writing some java code that essentially cleans messy data stored in table format from a flatfile (.CSV) source. All records are currently stored in String format even though some of the columns are obviously (at a sense check level) dates, dollar amounts and integers. I would like to store information based on what datatype each column could possibly be for better practice as the output will be directly imported into SQL.

To be clear on what I am after, for every record x where x is a string, I would like to check if x can possibly be converted into an int, double or date (the more granular the better). I have considered doing this using try & catch, trying to convert each record into each datatype respectively and recording whether an exception was caught or not. Surely there is a better way?

I hope the above is clear.

Cheers,

Josh

Answer (score 0):

I would start by listing every possible data type you will encounter. I would then list all possible string formats in your files for each data type.

I would then study the resulting lists of formats and determine whether what you want is even possible. Can a string between your delimiters be absolutely determined to be of exactly one type? It will help if, for each flat file, each column is a uniform type so you have more than one string format example to go by; even if individual values are of different formats, you can assume that there is one type for the column.

If that can be done, one way or another, then I recommend looking into regular expressions. I don't often do this, I think they are error-prone and overused, but I think they fit this case. You can create regular expressions to match each of the string formats in your list; if the string matches, that gives you your type, and you can then parse your value to the type of variable you want.

Note: I just realized I am not sure whether you expect to determine one type for each value; you say "store information based on what datatype each column could possibly be", as though you might convert one string to more than one type if possible. I missed it because that's unusual; am not sure what you will do with the multiple values, but if that's what you want it makes the programming easier, though the results are ambiguous.